# SQL Pivot rows to column header

Tags: sql, impala

I need to isolate the sales_credit_type_code in (ATR,AWT) to create 4 new columns for every customer_key.

Current table

[image: 1]

Desired Output

[image: 2]

Here is my code that's code is not working:

```
SELECT customer_key,

CASE sales_credit_type_code WHEN 'ATR' THEN dm_name END AS 'ATR DM Name',
CASE sales_credit_type_code WHEN 'ATR' THEN salesrep_name END AS 'ATR Salesrep Name',
CASE sales_credit_type_code WHEN 'AWT' THEN dm_name END AS 'AWT DM Name',
CASE sales_credit_type_code WHEN 'AWT' THEN salesrep_name END AS 'AWT Salesrep Name'
FROM aim_customer_zipterr_xref_transposed_vw
group by 1,2,3,4,5
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use aggregate function `group_concat`:

```
select customer_key ,
        group_concat(CASE sales_credit_type_code WHEN 'ATR' THEN dm_name END, ',') AS 'ATR DM Name',
        group_concat(CASE sales_credit_type_code WHEN 'ATR' THEN salesrep_name END,',') AS 'ATR Salesrep Name',
        group_concat(CASE sales_credit_type_code WHEN 'AWT' THEN dm_name END, ',')  AS 'AWT DM Name',
        group_concat(CASE sales_credit_type_code WHEN 'AWT' THEN salesrep_name END, ',')  AS 'AWT Salesrep Name'
FROM aim_customer_zipterr_xref_transposed_vw
group by customer_key
```

more info : [impala doc](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_group_concat.html#group_concat)

or if there is one per type:

```
select customer_key ,
        max(CASE sales_credit_type_code WHEN 'ATR' THEN dm_name END) AS 'ATR DM Name',
        max(CASE sales_credit_type_code WHEN 'ATR' THEN salesrep_name END,',') AS 'ATR Salesrep Name',
        max(CASE sales_credit_type_code WHEN 'AWT' THEN dm_name END)  AS 'AWT DM Name',
        max(CASE sales_credit_type_code WHEN 'AWT' THEN salesrep_name END)  AS 'AWT Salesrep Name'
FROM aim_customer_zipterr_xref_transposed_vw
group by customer_key
```

Comment: Thank you, @eshirvana. The results are duplicating across the other dimensions in the select statement. Is there any way to make the group_concat results distinct? I tried:

group_concat(Distinct CASE sales_credit_type_code WHEN 'ATR' THEN dm_name END, ',') AS 'Acute RSM',

group_concat(Distinct CASE sales_credit_type_code WHEN 'ATR' THEN salesrep_name END,',') AS 'Acute Rep',

group_concat(Distinct CASE sales_credit_type_code WHEN 'AWT' THEN dm_name END, ',')  AS 'OOH RSM',

group_concat(Distinct CASE sales_credit_type_code WHEN 'AWT' THEN salesrep_name END, ',')  AS 'OOH Rep',

Comment: @ChaseMekaelian , if you mean you are getting duplicate rows , then based on the provided sample data , you shouldn't , unless there are more to the story ;) , maybe provide a better sample data

Comment: also tried the max function and it wont work with a string